# Calculating difference between the min and max date and then compare it with current date value in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I have campaign data where i want to find the runtime based on min, max and current date.
For example:

I have data like:

```
Date         Campaign     
1.1.2020       A
2.1.2020       A
3.1.2020       A
1.1.2020       B
2.1.2020       B
```

I used min and max aggregation to find the min and max date value like this:

```
 df_min_max_date = df.groupby('Campaign')['Date'].agg(['min', 'max']).reset_index()

    Date         Campaign       min               max
        1.1.2020       A      1.1.2020          3.1.2020  
        2.1.2020       A      1.1.2020          3.1.2020  
        3.1.2020       A      1.1.2020          3.1.2020  
        1.1.2020       B      1.1.2020          2.1.2020
        2.1.2020       B      1.1.2020          2.1.2020
```

But now i need another column which explain the runtime:
The **desired output** would be like this

```
 Date         Campaign       min               max     runtime
 1.1.2020       A      1.1.2020          3.1.2020       0%
 2.1.2020       A      1.1.2020          3.1.2020       50%
 3.1.2020       A      1.1.2020          3.1.2020       100%
 1.1.2020       B      1.1.2020          2.1.2020        0%
 2.1.2020       B      1.1.2020          2.1.2020       100%
```

Comment: It would be easier if you expressed the values as the number of days, then you would use `apply` to calculate the runtime based on the min and the max.

Comment: First you should calculate the `delta = date_max - date_min`, than you need the time passed to the current date like `delta_current = date_today - date_min` and you just need to divide the delta values. I don't know the format of your date values, but I prefer to use the UNIX Timestamp, this makes such operations much easier.

Comment: I tried with this logic but somehow its showing 0 for all values.